# LangChain Agents: Conversational React Description

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, large-language-model

Previously I used `initialize_agent` method by passing `agent=AgentType.CONVERSATIONAL_REACT_DESCRIPTION` to initialize a conversation react agent in LangChain v0.0.

```
agent_executor = initialize_agent(tools=tools, llm=llm, memory=memory, verbose=True, max_iterations=3, handle_parsing_errors=True, agent=AgentType.CONVERSATIONAL_REACT_DESCRIPTION, agent_kwargs=prompt)
```

But in LangChain v1.0, it says that it will be deprecated and to use the `create_react_agent` method. I want to initialize an `CONVERSATIONAL_REACT_DESCRIPTION` agent.

```
# Construct the ReAct agent
agent = create_react_agent(llm=llm, tools=tools, prompt=template)
# Create an agent executor by passing in the agent and tools
agent_executor = AgentExecutor(agent=agent, tools=tools, max_iterations=3, handle_parsing_errors=True, verbose=True)
```

*langchain 0.1.11, langchain-community 0.0.27, langchain-core 0.1.30, langchain-google-genai 0.0.9, langchain-mistralai 0.0.5, langchain-openai 0.0.8, langchain-text-splitters 0.0.1, langsmith 0.1.23*

How to initiate a `CONVERSATIONAL_REACT_DESCRIPTION` in LangChain v0.1?